British moral/ethical dilemmas programme
Trying to find the name of this programme.
UK TV programme possibly Channel 4/BBC c80s/early 90s.  Aired Sunday mornings.  It featured a panel of professionals CEOs, lawyers, doctors, industry leaders etc, who are  posed with a moral/ethical dilemma to resolve.  Meanwhile, as the panel thrashes out their arguments, the moderator would contribute various scenarios to further the discussion and challenge the panel.  It resulted in a very lively, interesting and funny discussion.

There was a show on BBC in 1997/8 called Dilemma. With guests duscussing ethical situations

Thanks you so much for the information. I'll check all the suggestions but I think 'Hypertheticals' could be it. Dilemma could fit into the time frame, the 70s, rather than 80s or 90s (memory a bit fuzzy). I think I've checked the Moral Maze before but it's a different format to the programme I'm looking for. I'll do another search. Anyway, again very appreciative of your help in this matter. Best wishes

I think this might be Hypotheticals
From Helena Kennedy's (one of the moderators) page

This series analysed current affairs with leading politicians and policy-makers using hypothetical situations. 

I've also found a brief video on an unrelated site which indicates it may have aired on BBC2.

Round table debates on a hypothetical situation. MPs, Judges, Doctors and other decision makers tell how and why choices are made.

Also reference to a videotape here

Series exploring ethical issues surrounding social policy and the gap between theory and practice, using fictionalised case studies.
1 (producers Juliet Winstone, Linda Bell): Helena Kennedy QC and panel discuss how far should social services go in search of evidence to protect endangered children. Does their work ever compromise an individual’s right to privacy?
2: Vincent Hanna and panel discuss whether condoms should be freely available in children’s homes, and whether allegations by teenagers of sexual abuse will be believed.
3: David Mellor MP and panel discuss dilemmas involving the disabled elderly.


The BBC radio program The Moral Maze was given a trial run of 6 TV episodes in 1994.  Description from Wikipedia:

Four regular panellists discuss moral and ethical issues raised by a recent news story. Michael Buerk delivers a preamble launching the topic, then a series of 'witnesses' - experts or other relevant people - are questioned by the panellists, who then discuss what each witness said.

Guests included:

Claire Fox
Giles Fraser
Kenan Malik
Anne McElvoy
Michael Portillo
Melanie Phillips
Matthew Taylor


I found it.  It's called 'Bounds of Freedom', the moderator was Prof. Charles Nesson.  There are only excerpts available on UT but still a joy to watch.  Thank you NB: spelling error in last post 'hypothetical'

The series described by the OP was called "Hypotheticals". There were, I think, two separate runs of three programmes each. 
One memory from me: Trevor McDonald was a panellist on one show which included consideration of a conflagration in the Middle East. He was invited on board an "enemy" ship to interview a foreign leader. Allied forces discovered that the foreign leader was on board and had to decide whether or not to send planes in to attack it and destabilise the enemy action, knowing Trevor was on board. 
Vincent Hanna kept introducing new twists to each scenario and obtaining reactions from a range of politicians, journalists, business leaders and other experts.  The panellists were generally really thoughtful and non-political in their responses and decisions.
The only thing that has come close to this was the recent film (drama) Eye in the Sky, where the viewer sees differing reactions and priorities being exhibited by a range of stakeholders to an urgently developing situation.  
